# Node Monitor Path in eclipse for nodeclipse

Tags: node.js, nodeclipse

I started learning node.js, configured plugins for node.js in eclipse. What should I set in "Node monitor Path" field in windows preference under Nodeclipse settings?

Answer (score 4):

This function was add in Nodeclipse 0.6, but no feedback came on how it should be. Authors are not using this features, so
as of Nodeclipse 0.12, all monitors were not tested. see http://www.nodeclipse.org/history
So hopefully more answers show how to do that.

Launching logic is in 
https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.debug/src/org/nodeclipse/debug/launch/LaunchConfigurationDelegate.java#L147-162

Nodeclipse is free open-source project that grows with your contributions.
Do not expect authors to do features they themselves do not use.
Once there is person raising the issue and willing to follow it, it gets solved.

There is built-in and online Help:
Press F1 -> Contents -> [Nodeclipse Help - Monitor page](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.help/contents/monitor.md)

Select monitor

- https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever
- https://www.npmjs.org/package/nodemon
- https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-dev
- https://www.npmjs.org/package/supervisor

They all have similar command line

forever [action] [options] SCRIPT [script-options]
nodemon [your node app]
node-dev foo.js
supervisor [options]

Below are some remarks about GitHub stars:

- [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) - 2700 stars
- [node-dev](https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev) - 380 stars (doesn't require any configuration)
- [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) 1500 stars - support running .coffee
- [supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) 1100 stars

After installing with `npm install * -g`, browse for CLI file

e.g. `C:\Users\weibl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\forever\bin\forever`

Configure path to your source file monitor in Preferences -> Nodeclipse -> Node monitor path

So as you can notice Help also grows when issue are raised and solved. Check [Tasks view in Eclipse not showing TODOs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881044/tasks-view-in-eclipse-not-showing-todos) for example

Comment: for someone new to node, this answer is cryptic at best. What exactly is needed to setup and specify the node monitor?

Comment: Updated. Now is your turn

Comment: thank you, nodemon is happily restarting my server now on code changes-

Comment: Could you please share e.g. on wiki https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/wiki